# android clear intent which send from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

My app is getting called by an intent that is passing information(pendingintent in statusbar) but when I hit the home button and reopen my app by holding the home button it calls the intent again and the same extras are still there...

is there any way to clear the intent? or check whether it has been used before?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("reportID", reportID);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    intent.putExtra("toast_show", true);
    intent.putExtra("detail_open", true);
    intent.putExtra("SplashActivity", true);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                            | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    // Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    /* get the system service that manage notification NotificationManager */
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context.getApplicationContext())
            .setWhen(when)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSmallIcon(smalIcon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(message)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setDefaults(
                    Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS
                            | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE
                            | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    /* Create notification with builder */
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

The problem starts when I receive a notification. If I start the app from the notification, it starts the correct screen and I can use the app => ok. But when I quit the app (with home or back button) it do not appears anymore in the "recent app" list. More precisely:
Does anyone knows how to keep the app in the "recent app" list after being started form a notification?

Comment: Please check this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743184/android-notification-how-to-bring-the-activity-to-front-without-recall-the-act
May be it will work in your case

Comment: Did your problem solved? I got the same problem

Comment: @Ponting yes i solved it.

Comment: @kyogs : How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Update this line and try

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int)(Math.random() * 100),intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: i also tried with your solution but still getting all data when i start application by long press of home button and it will start again with old intent data..:(

Answer (score -1):

What you need is the [`PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT) :

> If the described PendingIntent already exists, the current one is canceled before generating a new one. You can use this to retrieve a new PendingIntent when you are only changing the extra data in the Intent; by canceling the previous pending intent, this ensures that only entities given the new data will be able to launch it.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
               context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

This will ensure that your latest data will pe present on your `Intent`.

Comment: my problem is that when i open activity from notification center and i got all value from intent but now i press back button so application is finished but now again open application by long press of home button and then again i got all data in this intent but i want this data null.